FFMPEG: Black background for transparent overlay
I'm trying to create some overlays over a video using c# but I can't get the overlay to be transparentOverlay to be transparent.
            for (int i = 0; i < textModelList.Count; i++)
            {
                var textModel = textModelList[i];

                // Text overlay properties
                string textColor = ConvertHexToFFmpegColor(textModel.TextColour, includeAlpha: false);
                string backgroundColor = textModel.BackgroundColour == null
                    ? "0x00000000"  // Fully transparent
                    : ConvertHexToFFmpegColor(textModel.BackgroundColour);

                // Calculate scaled overlay dimensions
                int overlayWidth = (int)(textModel.LabelWidth * scaleFactorX);
                int overlayHeight = (int)(textModel.LabelHeight * scaleFactorY);

                var xPosition = (textModel.Position_X + textModel.InitialX) * scaleFactorX;
                var yPosition = (textModel.Position_Y + textModel.InitialY) * scaleFactorY;

                string fontFilePath = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "Fonts", "NewWaltDisneyFontRegular-BPen.otf");

                var startTime = TimeSpan.FromTicks(textModel.StartTime).Seconds;
                var endTime = TimeSpan.FromTicks((int)textModel.EndTime).Seconds;

                string formattedFontFilePath = FormatFontFilePath(fontFilePath);

                int fontSize = (int)(textModel.Font_Size * Math.Min(scaleFactorX, scaleFactorY));

                // Create text overlay image with scaled dimensions
                string overlayImage = $"text_overlay_{Guid.NewGuid().ToString()}.png";

                int rotationAngle = (int)textModel.Rotation;
                string rotationFilter = $", rotate={rotationAngle}*PI/180:fillcolor=0x00000000:ow=rotw(iw):oh=roth(ih)";

                // Create a transparent overlay
                string transparentOverlay = $"transparent_overlay_{Guid.NewGuid().ToString()}.png";
                string createTransparentOverlayCommand = $"-f lavfi -i color=c=0x00000000:s={overlayWidth}x{overlayHeight} -vf \"format=rgba\" -frames:v 1 {transparentOverlay}";
                await ExecuteFFmpegCommand(createTransparentOverlayCommand);

                string createOverlayCommand = $"-i {transparentOverlay} -vf \"drawtext=fontfile={formattedFontFilePath}:text='{textModel.Text}':x=(w-text_w)/2:y=(h-text_h)/2:fontsize={fontSize}:fontcolor={textColor}:box=1:boxcolor={backgroundColor}{rotationFilter}\" -frames:v 1 {overlayImage}";
                await ExecuteFFmpegCommand(createOverlayCommand);

                // Prepare the overlay command for this textModel
                string overlayCommand = $"-noautorotate -i \"{currentInputFile}\" -i {overlayImage} -filter_complex \"overlay={xPosition}:{yPosition}:enable='between(t,{startTime},{endTime})'\" -codec:a copy";

                // Create a temporary output file for this stage
                tempOutputFile = $"E:\\TempOutput\\temp_output_{i}.mp4";

                // Apply the overlay and save to the temporary file
                await ExecuteFFmpegCommand($"{overlayCommand} \"{tempOutputFile}\"");

                // Update current input to be the output of this stage
                
                

It's this command here:
    string createTransparentOverlayCommand = $"-f lavfi -i color=c=0x00000000:s={overlayWidth}x{overlayHeight} -vf \"format=rgba\" -frames:v 1 {transparentOverlay}";

It always appears with a black background rather than transparent.

try ... -i color=blue@0:{overlayWidth}x{overlayHeight},format=rgba -frames:v 1 ...
